# process.BasePriority threw an Exception of Type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

When I am trying to start a process from web API locally its started successfully but when I am hosting it to IIS 7.5 and try to start that process there is no response I am getting. when I tried to debug attaching the process to visual studio and start a debug I seen this error Process's BaseProperty

```
process.BasePriority threw an Exception of Type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

I am starting a process to start a cmd.exe and here is the code:

```
public static void Start(long campaign_id, long contact_id, string startDate, string endDate, string user)
    {
        try
        {
            //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c sparkclr-submit --master " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SparkMaster"] + " --driver-class-path " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine\\mysql.jar " + "--exe CmAnalyticsEngine.exe " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine " + campaign_id + " " + contact_id + " " + startDate + " " + endDate + " " + user;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            //startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("process is running");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("process is stopped");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogWritter.WriteErrorLog(e);
        }
    }
```

when I am running this locally it works properly but on IIS its printing msg **Process is stopped**.

do I need to give **permission to cmd.exe** to start from IIS? if yes then how to do it?

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error means the process has exited.-or- The process has not started, so there is no process ID.

```
public static void Start(long campaign_id, long contact_id, string startDate, string endDate, string user)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/c sparkclr-submit --master " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SparkMaster"] + " --driver-class-path " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine\\mysql.jar " + "--exe CmAnalyticsEngine.exe " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine " + campaign_id + " " + contact_id + " " + startDate + " " + endDate + " " + user;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
        //startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("process is running");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("process is stopped");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogWritter.WriteErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.